# IMAP-Can not view contents in outlook

Tags: c++, outlook, imap, winsock

i have implemented an IMAP client (using winsock and openssl) that can fetch emails from my GMail account and save each individual email as .eml file. However, i was not able to view the content using outlook.
I also tried EAgetmail to download email and i can view them in outlook.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/eagetmail.png/?sa=0 "Eagetmail viewed in notepad"
  http://postimg.org/image/ma635e0xx/ "Eagetmail viewed in outlook"

http://postimg.org/image/xo9piny5f/ "Winsock viewed in notepad"

http://postimg.org/image/oa8tvzo9v/ "winsock viewed in outlook"

I also tried to edit the content of so that it looks similar to the content of Eagetmail but it still does not work. However, if i copy and paste the entire content of EAgetmail then i was able to view it in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The actual text looks ok, i.e. looks like a correct MIME format.  Since you're able to cut/paste it and have it load okay, I suspect something is wrong with the encoding of the file that gets cleared up on the clipboard.  Maybe the line endings?  Look at it with a hex editor in before and after paste to see what's different.

Comment: Thanks for reply. you were right, it is the line ending that is different.. I just downloaded hex editor and look at the content of the 2 files and i saw that in file of Eagetmail, the line is ending with 0x0D (carriage return) followed by 0x0A(new line) but in the file that i fetched using winsock, the line is ending in 2 consecutive 0x0d and followed by 0x0a, i think this is what causing outlook unable to read. 

http://postimg.org/image/slip111zv/  "Eagetmail"

http://postimg.org/image/49s76cl3l/ "winsock"

I don't know how to fix this problem, i basically fetching whatever Gmail gave me.

Comment: Technically Outlook should be able to view a MIME file with CR-CR-LF since it's basically a normal line that happens to end with CR.  It looks like its MIME decoder is being picky.  It would not be hard to parse the response from the IMAP server to remove the extra CR from the line termination before you write out the file.  While you're at it, I'd also check for the situation of lack of CR (i.e. LF only).